# How to count duplicates and show them as one

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I've an object class called `Students` in which I have `Student Name`,`Contact` and `Twitter Handle`. Now as I fetch this data from firebase I'm storing it in an array which is `var students: [Student] = []`. Using firestore I'm running the query and storing the results in the array as:

```
let studentObj = Student(dictionary: querySnapShot.data()!)
self.students.append(studentObj!)
```

Inside `querySnapShot.data()` the data of Students can be duplicate. Meaning there can be similar students who are appearing more than one time.

I want to count those duplicate students e.g. if `Ava` is three times in the data it should count it and display it as `Ava (3)` in the tableview cell. I did that using a dictionary `var studentCapCount = [String: Int]()` and a function:

```
func countStudents(studentArray: [Student]) {
    for item in studentArray {

        studentCapCount[item.name] = studentCapCount[item.name] ?? 0 + 1
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**The problem:**

The function is counting correctly but when it comes to display there is a problem. As I'm only using `item.name` so I can't figure out how to show **student name**, **contact** and **twitter** in `cellForRowAt` method of `tableView`. Like what should I write here:

```
    cell.textLabel?.text =  ??
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Contact: \(students[indexPath.row].contact) | Twitter: \(students[indexPath.row].twitter)"
```

If I return `students.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` that's a problem because it'll also include duplicate values count but if I do `studentCapCount.count` that's also a problem because I cannot print the `detailTextLabel?.text` because of the no. of rows.

**Student Class Code:**

```
struct Student {

    var name: String
    var contact: String
    var twitter: String


    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "contact": contact,
            "twitter": twitter
        ]
    }
}

extension PoliticianMarker {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
        let contact = dictionary["contact"] as? String,
        let twitter = dictionary["twitter"] as? String
            else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(name: name, contact:contact, twitter:twitter)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple students with same name and different contact and twitter?

Comment: @PGDev That can also happen. Is there a way we can do this on `student` object? Otherwise I'll have to make this change at the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conform `Student` to **`Hashable`** and implement `==` and `hash(into:)` methods,

```
struct Student: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var contact: String
    var twitter: String

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
        hasher.combine(contact)
        hasher.combine(twitter)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.contact == rhs.contact && lhs.twitter == rhs.twitter
    }
}
```

Now, you can group the duplicate `Student` instances using `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`**, i.e.

```
var students = [Student(name: "Alex", contact: "1234", twitter: "XYZ"), Student(name: "Alex", contact: "1234", twitter: "XYZ"), Student(name: "Mike", contact: "98765", twitter: "XYZ"), Student(name: "Mike", contact: "09876", twitter: "PQR")]

let dict = Dictionary(grouping: students, by: { $0.hashValue })
```

Next, get the `students` from `dict` using `compactMap(_:)` like so,

```
students = dict.compactMap({
    var countText = ""
    if $0.value.count > 1 {
        countText = " x\( $0.value.count)"
    }
    var student = $0.value.first
    student?.name += countText
    return student
})
```

Finally, use `students` as your `tableView's` `dataSource`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just one question, is there a way I can modify the code you shared to show `x2` with name label. Lets say from the code example you gave I'll need to show `Alex x2` as it appeared 2 times.